# Why is project and file saving/management so awkward in programming as compared to other digital media?

Tags: visual-studio, file, save

TLDR: What is the reason for the complex file management systems in place, such as Github repositories, when working in Visual Studio?

---

This has been bothering me for a while. I've finished a diploma course in Digital Media, and have started another course in programming. One thing that stuck out immediately after coming from 3D art is how incredibly awkward and obtuse basic file management is when working with Visual Studio. Presumably the same issues arise with other development environments, as if they didn't I can't imagine why anybody would ever use VS.

For example, let's say I want to work on a project in 3ds Max. It's stored on a shared network drive, so I don't want to risk two people accessing it at the same time and saving over each others work. I simply grab the folder or file that I want to use, copy and paste it with a new name, and then I'm good to go.

Saving things with a new name is easy, just save as, rename it. I can work from network drives, local drives, portable drives. The file can come from anywhere and be saved anywhere. Everything is fast, painless, and clear.

If I was to try and do the same thing in VS, for starters, it wouldn't let me build the program while saved to the network, so I'd have to copy it over to a local drive. Presumably this is to prevent the "multiple people accessing, saving over each other" issues that are easily avoided by just renaming the thing.

If I wanted to iteration save, that is, to frequently save the project with a version number name to allow easy rollbacks and troubleshooting, I'm not even sure how I'd do it. Renaming projects/solutions has proven so hard to do that I've had to delete projects and make them again with a new name, rather than try and figure out how to it properly.

There are all sorts of complex file management systems that VS seems to require for any large project work, all of which would be completely unnecessary if you could just copy, paste, rename and save-as with any real ease.

I'm obviously rather new to this, and I'm certain that there is an important reason why it's so awkward to manage files, I just don't know what that reason is. I feel like I'd have a far better understanding of how all these file management systems actually work if I knew why they existed in the first place. At the moment, just trying to be able to work from a network drive is taking up hours when it would be a non-issue in every other digital media field I've worked with.

Comment: TL; DR: You're doing it wrong and don't understand how it should be done. How does using version control relate to "complex file management system"? Version control is exactly the way to "allow easy rollbacks" and there is nothing complicated about handling files with Visual Studio. And no, VS doesn't require any management systems. It seems you don't really have any understanding of the subject and frankly this is probably off topic at SO.

Comment: Also why do you want to work from a network share?

Comment: I want to work from a network share because I'm working at a campus with hundreds of computers. If I'm working locally, that project is only on one computer. If I want to work on it and can't get that exact computer, the project cannot be accessed. Every user account on the network has a partition of a network drive that can be accessed from any computer, only by them. Saving things to that network drive is expected.

Comment: Visual Studio by itself doesn't restrict the use of network shares and doesn't care if millions poke on the files at once. You're blaming the tool while the problem is elsewhere. What is the error that you get while trying to use? .NET not allowing running from shares?

Comment: As for the first comment. Version Control is a complex file management system. If it's not save as with a new name, or copy and paste the folder with a new name, it's now using a system. For a complete newbie, these systems are incredibly obtuse, and seemingly unnecessary. I know that they are necessary, because they wouldn't exist if they weren't, but I have no idea why.

Comment: The error I get is that it requires that I deploy the program before building it, and won't let me deploy from a network share. If this isn't default behaviour, then I don't know how to "turn it off".

Comment: Obtuse... I'd say not. And nobody forces you to use them. VS doesn't. You choose or not to use them. You can copy the files with a different name if you want and that's it. Just like with any other. But version control is simple and much less problematic than copying around with random names.

Comment: Why is it simpler and less problematic? That isn't the case with other media. That's my question. As a newbie from a different field, something like Version Control shouldn't exist. It does, and I know it wouldn't if it weren't needed or preferred.

Comment: As I said, you're free to copy files around if you want. But when you want to compare, roll back, not have 20483837 files around and wonder what's the difference and myriads of other reasons. So you can choose. If you dot want to keep proper track of changes and have an easy rollback, just make copies of files and try to remember what's what. Nothing is saying you can't. And how do you compare "with other media" what you changed? How often do you need to? With code, often.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Version Control is used because the system allows you to more easily compare versions, either by system features or by simply adding notes? That's an actually useful feature, and would make me want to use something like Version Control. That's the sort of answer I'm looking for.

With other media, iteration saves are present due to the risk of crashes. We save regularly to prevent corruption and allow rolling back before irreversible changes. Comparison between them isn't very common, as they're iterations, not variations.

Comment: One example: you made seven changes to a project, all around the code. The third one caused a bug. How do you remove only that one and keep the rest? With VC it's easy. With copying files around not so much. Please do read a tutorial to version control, it will make things clearer. And it's not like other media wouldn't need version control. I'm sure many people would love to have a proper history of things done on a complex 3D scene and be able to revert any change made in the past without changing anything done afterwards etc

Comment: That would be nice to have in 3D, but can easily be accomplished by just grabbing the new elements and old elements and saving a new scene. I wonder what's been changed from the default with the VS I'm running to make it so awkward. Renaming causes errors sometimes. Can't build from network. Stuff just feels clunky and fragile, like if I do anything unusual the whole project will break.